# Add shortcode inside of the_content()

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, the-content

I have a custom post type (events) and i made a custom template for archive and for single.

On single i want to add a shortcode to every post, this shortcode provides all dynamic data of the current post.

How can i input the shortcode in the_content() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the_content Hook: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_shortchode_in_single_page' );
function my_shortchode_in_single_page($content){
    if(is_single())
        return $content . do_shortcode('YOUR SHORTCODE HERE');

    return $content;
}
```